# How to add html attribute without value in @Html.BeginForm

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("", "actionname", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "card-activate-form" , data_parsley_validate="true" }))
```

will render

```
<form action="actionname" data-parsley-validate="true" id="card-activate-form" method="post">
```

but ideally it should be 'data-parsley-validate' only

```
<form action="actionname" data-parsley-validate id="card-activate-form" method="post">
```

how to add data-parsley-validate only in the form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement it with `string.Empty` or `""` like following

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("", "actionname", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "card-activate-form" , data_parsley_validate="" })) @*//or string.Empty*@
```

it will produce

```
<form action="actionname" data-parsley-validate id="card-activate-form" method="post">
```

Comment: thanks a lot.  tested and working.   thanks again for the help

Comment: @Kruze You are welcome:) if it worked for you, please consider to accept the answer to help people understand problem has been solved